# Specifying the hardcoded value for tag of object animator is creating black screen between two fragments

Tags: android

I m getting a problem on implementing of animation between two fragments. Flip or slide transition can be occurred between two fragments. Flip animation is not creating any problem. But for example slide_right, Here I am specifying hard coded value for `valueFrom` and `valueTo`, so for higher resolution there will be black screen between two fragments. How I can solve it? Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm actually having a similar problem with the new animator framework, namely objectAnimator and the property translationX. Did you find out how to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use percent values like that:

slide_in_right.xml:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
android:fromXDelta="100%p"
android:toXDelta="0"
android:zAdjustment="top" />
```

Comment: I can't use it. It will be used, if i put it within anim folder. If i use it i can't use flip animation. Becuase I have to use setCustomAnimations for making animation. Here I have to specify xml. using supportfragment api, I can't use objectanimator. So I can't use xml for making flip animation!!

Comment: I tried it. within xml file, I have used  com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator. But it is throwing unknown animator name. what i am doing wrong??